# Textmate and PHP - having some trouble with the bundle

Tags: php, editor, textmate

I've been using Textmate for Ruby/Python scripting for awhile and now have a need to hack on some PHP. I'm having some troubles with the bundle:

1. The code-highlighting doesn't support HTML...
2. When I type `php` + tab TM spits out:

   ```
   ?><?php>
   ```

   instead of:

   ```
   <?php ?>
   ```

Anyone know where I could possibly be going wrong? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your file type to HTML (even if you are editing a .php file!) would solve the problem.

The reason for this is documented at http://wiki.macromates.com/Troubleshooting/PHPSyntaxHighlight

Comment: I think the reason for that is you only need one <?php at the beginning of a PHP file; thus, typing php + tab means you want to insert some HTML in between.

Answer (score 1):

No, the best way is to set language to "HTML" in the bottom status bar.

[image: status bar, change to "HTML"]

you can still have the file name ended with php